# Displaying values in ListView according to correct month

Tags: java, android, listview, android-calendar

I'm a student and I'm studying Java&Android development.

I'm working on my final project for the college and I'm having some troubles achieving my need.

Let's say I have a fragment layout with the current date on top, 2 buttons to navigate between the months beside the date.
Below the date, I have a ListView which should show the correct values according to the current month shown on top.
Below the ListView, I have a "bottom bar" that shows data as well as the ListView.

Image for better understanding:

[image: Image for better understanding]

What I'm trying to achieve is, when I'll click on next or previous month buttons - it will replace the values in ListView and bottom bar with the correct values according to the correct month, some kind of a dynamic ListView according to months.

What is the best way to achieve this?

I'm using firebase if that makes some kind of sense.
Thank you for your time! :)

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Now I have the current date, 2 buttons (next , previous) to navigate between the months, a ListView and the bottom bar. The next/prev buttons works fine, it displays the correct date but the ListView & bottom stays static on every month. I'll attach a screenshot of what I'm exactly looking for

Comment: @Geno Chen Image attached